# Java: How do I pass a int value higher than 128 in a Outputstream

Tags: java, embedded, arrays, outputstream

I have an embedded system I have to integrate my Java application with. So far my work has been going well except now I have come across a problem where I need to send the number 160 as a bit. The OutputStream will only accept a byte[] and when I try to insert 160 (hex value 0xA0) into the array it is converted to -96. I understand that Java byte only supports signed values (-127 to 128), so I was wondering if anyone else has had a similar problem dealing with embedded systems and what their solution was.

Here is some sample code:

```
OutputStream oStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
byte attributeCode = (byte)0xA0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
buffer[command.length + 1] = attributeCode;
oStream.write(buffer);
```

The embedded system is written in C and has been around for years, so no chance to have that changed.

Answer (score 1):

The byte is exactly the same whether it's being treated as a signed byte with value -96, or an unsigned byte with value 160.  This won't have any adverse effect on the C program on the other end; the only difference is what happens when you try printing out the value in Java.

In other words, you have no problem.

Comment: If OP needs to print it, this will work. `((int)attributeCode & 0xFF)`